# How angular controllers bind with view?

Tags: angularjs, typescript, hawtio

I dont understand how controllers is connecting with views in Hawtio project.

for example, view:

```
<div ng-controller="Core.AboutController">
  <div class="welcome">
    <div class="about-display" compile="html"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

controller declaration:

```
module Core {
  export function AboutController($scope, $location, jolokia, branding, localStorage) {
    //...
  }
  //...
}
```

I expected to find something like that:

```
angular.module('moduleName').controller('Core.AboutController', Core.AboutController);
```

But found none. How it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works because in the absence of any registration with angular i.e. `angular.module('moduleName').controller('Core.AboutController'` angular looks at `window` and tries to resolve it. Which is what

```
module Core {
  export function AboutController
```

does. After this line `window.Core.AboutController` will point to the correct function and that is what angular just found.

Answer (score 1):

just look at the attribute in the first line of the HTML sample you posted.

```
ng-controller="Core.AboutController"
```

There are (As far as I know) two ways of associating a view to a controller. The first is with a an attribute, like in this example. The second is while configuring the router:

```
angular.module('MyApp', ['Core.Aboutcontrollers']).
config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/path', {templateUrl: 'partials/myfile.html'   });
}]);
```

Don't do both of them, or your controller will be invoked twice.

Comment: `angular.module('MyApp', ['Core.Aboutcontrollers']).` is wrong. You just put a controller in place of an angular module.

Comment: It's the way it's done in angular seed, which is as you certainly know a widely used angular project template: https://github.com/angular/angular-seed/blob/master/app/js/app.js. It does not remplace the module, it defines a dependency between the module and the controller.

Comment: my app.controllers is a module. Not a controller https://github.com/angular/angular-seed/blob/master/app/js/app.js#L10